# How can I center an ion-fab button within an ion-tabs component in Ionic?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic5

How can I center a floating button with a label exactly in the center of an ion-tabs component? I'm facing an issue where the display gets shifted to the right on certain mobile devices, as shown in the photo.

```html
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
      <ion-icon name="albums-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Albums</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
      <ion-icon name="people-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Accounts</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button></ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab3">
      <ion-icon name="card-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Card</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab4">
      <ion-icon name="settings-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Settings</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
<ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="center" slot="fixed">
  <ion-fab-button>
    <ion-icon name="add-outline"></ion-icon>
  </ion-fab-button>
  <ion-label>Sinistres</ion-label>
</ion-fab>
```

[image: Image 1]

Comment: it will be in centre if you remove label from it.

Comment: I need to show label

Comment: Wrap it in a div and use ion-text to show your label. dont use ion-label.